# getting the name of variable after splitting

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario like this------

```
right = some_function (some_value)
var idR =right.split('~')[0];
var r =right.split('~')[1];

left = another-func (some_value)
var idL = left.split('~')[0];
var l =  left.split('~')[1];
```

point to be noted that r,l contains numeric values. 
My purpose is that I want to take the maximum between r and l, and after that I will traverse back to 'right' or 'left' according to maximum value of r or l.

I am using math.max() but this is not working as it only returns the value, not the name of variable.

How can I achieve my goal???

Let me provide some sample inputs and outputs--
"some_function" returns a string in the format "id~value" where "id" can be "1-1", "2-2" and so on and "value" can be any numeric value. I need to look at the greater "value" and fetch its corresponding "id". Note that "another_func" returns values in same pattern

MY CODE IS NOT THESE TWO BLOCKS ONLY, I HAVE EIGHT FUNCTIONS LIKE THESE AND I HAVE TO TAKE THE BIGGEST NUMBER AND ITS CORRESPONDING ID

Comment: I believe you want something like: `var dir = Math.max(l, r) == l ? idL : idR;`

Comment: @FelixKling: shouldn't it be `Math.max(l, r) == l`? as Math.max returns a number, and `split` returns a string, type & value checks will always be false

Comment: I am not getting you. would you please give with example like what your some_function will give and what exact value you required

Comment: @Elias: Right... fixed! Thanks :) (converting the values to numbers like `var r = +right.split('~')[1];` would be even better IMO).

Comment: some_function returns "1-1~5" for example.. another_func returns "2-1~6". I need to compare 5 and 6 and then traverse back to either 1-1 or 2-2. As 6>5, I will take "2-1". Please let me know if you need other details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.

Let's try this, so you have 2 arrays with values r and l and 2 arrays with variable names idR and adL.

Now this is what's not clear, do those arrays containing variable names have the same order? the same values? can this condition be trusted?

You clearly want to get some max value from the values arrays that's ok, but you aren't explaining how the other arrays fit on the picture :) After you do, probably me or someone else can help you :)

Comment: Sorry for not explaining properly. "some_function" returns a string in the format of "id~value" where "id" can be "1-1","2-2" and so on and "value" is any numeric value. My job is to look at the maximum value and fetch its id

Comment: ah ok :) So in that case you have to do something like "if(r > l) return idr; else return idl;" Nothing too fancy and it should work =) this is if those variables aren't new arrays themselves.

Comment: MY BAD..didnt explain more accuarately. I have eight functions so cant do the comparison like yours..

Comment: well, in that case, if you can get the maximum value by calling math.Max() somehow, then all you have to do next is check which id that belongs to. Like if (r == value) return idr; else if (l == value) return idl; ... (and so on).

Comment: math.Max() doesnt return variable name, it only returns the value, I need ID.

Comment: yes :) read my answer again. after you have the value, you then have to make some kind of iteration to see which ID has that value, like so the one i exampled. There is no good way (that i'm seeing at the moment) to do what you want with the base you are giving. :)

Comment: Yes there is, just not a good one :) i will try later (after work) to provide such a working example ok? :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, work takes my time :) so a way of solving this would be something like this code: 
  var vals = ["a~10", "b~13", "c~25", "d~9", "e~4", "f~7"];
  
  function getBiggerID()
  {
   var biggestVal = null;
   var biggestID = null;
   
   var parts;
   for (var i=0; i< vals.length; i++)
   {
    parts = vals[i].split('~');
    if (biggestVal == null || biggestVal < Number(parts[1]))
    {
     biggestVal =  Number(parts[1]);
     biggestID = parts[0];
    }
   }
   
   return biggestID;
  }
  
  alert("The biggest ID is : " + getBiggerID());
  
this would output c, (continues)

Comment: (continued) now the only thing you would have to do is change the method of constructing the array vals. Hope this helps.